# Jetpack Loop Order?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I've noticed that I need the fruit jetpack and the bubble gun jetpack for the achievements that I need on Jetpack Joyride and I was just wondering if there was a certain order that the jetpacks are released in. If there is a specific order could someone list it? Or at least let me know if there is an order or not.

Comment: I think it is random, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows Phone 8 I have both available for purchase for coins. On my Goggle Nexus tab I don't have ether one. They probably alternate of releasing content between platforms instead of releasing on multiple platforms at once.

Comment: I notice that sometimes jetpacks are available, and other times not. For instance: I had the option to buy the Flying V Jetpack, I didn't and now it's not there anymore. I think it just shows you a certain amount at any one time.